# QGIS "not responding" as reaction to every type of action

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, installation, windows

I just newly installed QGIS 3.16 because I got a new Laptop:

> Lenovo ThinkPad T490s 
>  i5-8265 
>  8 GB RAM 
>  256 GB SSD)

But when I try to use the program, it always goes into the "not responding" mode. It happens when I click on whatever part of QGIS (whether it be the task bar, starting a new project or the browser window), it even happens when I try to enlarge the window.

I already tried it with reinstalling, restarting the computer and installing the 3.10 version, but for days now nothing has changed.

Because I have to wait for about a minute after every click/action I make, I'm practically unable to work with QGIS. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: Some troubleshooting tips (so not an answer): try disabling your plugins (either start QGIS with `--noplugins` argument on the command line, or manually disable all plugins in the plugin manager dialog and restart), open your task manager and see if anything is using lots of CPU or memory.

Comment: And another thing to check: do you have many network drives mapped? If so, you can hide those drives that are irrelevant to GIS work, then QGIS  responds better. This is done in the Browser tab, right click on the irrelevant drive and choose "Hide"

Comment: Thank you. Yes the problem was the network drives. The problem actually only occurs when a network drive is disconnected. Either closing the browser tab or hiding the networks helped to fix it. In order to be able to do that first I had to connect to the networks so QGis would not become unresponsive.

Comment: This is actually a really useful string of comments. Would someone of you care to turn this into an answer and maybe edit the question to relflect the relevant culprits?

Comment: Also, how do you display hidden network drives again once they're gone? That would be a nice additional tidbit in an eventual answer ;)

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this, for re-showing hidden paths and network drives: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33164#issuecomment-708651902

Comment: @Micha This is, I think the best hint I have ever gotten! You just saved me from seriously committing suicide, I was desperate because of my unusable QGIS! Thank you so much for that idea!!!

Answer (score 16):

I had the same "not responding" problem. As recommended, I closed the browser tab and now it seems to work.

Quoted from comments:

> If you have many network drives mapped, you can hide those drives that are irrelevant to GIS work, then
> QGIS responds better. This is done in the Browser tab, right click on
> the irrelevant drive and choose "Hide"
>
> Yes the problem was the network drives. The problem actually only
> occurs when a network drive is disconnected. Either closing the
> browser tab or hiding the networks helped to fix it. In order to be
> able to do that first I had to connect to the networks so QGIS would
> not become unresponsive.

Also check out this comment on QGIS Issues: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33164#issuecomment-708651902

> Connect to your VPN/Network drive → QGIS should start up without
> problems
>
> in QGIS browser, right-click on the network drive and click "Hide from
> Browser" → QGIS will work as fast and without bugs as before, you can
> disconnect from VPN/network drive now
>
> [image]
>
> If you want to show the hidden drive in the Browser again, go to
> Settings -> Options -> Advanced -> Browser -> hidden Paths -> edit the
> line or right-click -> delete setting
>
> [image]
>
> otherwise drag-and-drop will workaround the browser problem completely

Comment: I've had this issue with QGIS being slow in Windows forever and got stuck in the rabbit hole of profiles and trying to clean temporary memory without avail. This worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue with QGIS ver. 3.26.2 and 3.26.3. Both closing the "Browser Panel" or hiding all network drives did the trick. Thanks!