# QGIS under Windows 10 freeze repeatedly

Tags: qgis-3

I recently purchased a new PC (OS: Windows 10 Pro, ver. 20H2, build 19042.868), into which I installed one after another (with clean installations) different single versions of QGis (3.10.14, 3.16.4, 3.18), but every release, with any different project I work with, gives me the same annoying problem: QGIS freezes repeatedly, for a time ranging from a few seconds to a few minutes, anytime I launch any type of command (editing, adding/removing layers, panning/zooming, etc…): it is not really possible to work with QGIS…
Further detail: any external plugin is disabled.
In addition to that, in the same machine, I installed, under Oracle VM, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and QGis 3.18: in this case the QGis works just fine.
Should I then assume that it is in OS problem?
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379226/qgis-not-responding-as-reaction-to-every-type-of-action/388441#388441

Comment: The problem seems solved! Thank you!

Comment: is it with the related link? (if yes I'll close the question as a duplicate so others know it is the same problem/solution)

Comment: Yes, your indication is right.